# tomcat context setting and URL issue

Tags: java, url, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a web app run in tomcat 8. I want to change the access URL.

I use the tomcat default `manager` app for example.

With the default config, the `manager` app locates on `webapps` folder.  The `manager` means the app name. But if I don't want to expose the app name and want the app to be accessed by `localhost:8080/tomcat-manager`, what should I do?

According the official documents, I modified the context.xml in `manager/META-INF` folder. My `context.xml` is as below:

```
<Context path="/tomcat-manager" docBase="manager"> </Context>
```

Then I think I can access the `manager` app by `localhost:8080/tomcat-manager`, but it doesn't work.

So I want to know how can I do this?

Comment: You run your app deploying war or by "start a server" in IDE? You should put `<Context path="...">` in `server.xml`, not `context.xml`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou In official documents, it's not recommanded to put the `Context` in `server.xml`, because can't be reload without restart tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-name the folder called `manager` to `tomcat-manager` and you are done.

Read [the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming) for more information.

**UPDATE**

You should never specify path in your `META-INF/context.xml` file: the path will be determined from the name of the WAR file. Also, never specify the docBase in `META-INF/context.xml`, because the `docBase` is already known (the `META-INF/context.xml` is *already* relative to something: the `docBase`).

That said, if you use an external `context.xml` file (e.g. in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[engine]/[host]/[appname].xml` then you *must* specify a `docBase` pointing to your WAR file (or exploded WAR directory). You will still never use `path` in that file.

Comment: I know this is ok, but what the use of the configuration in `context.xml` `path` and `docBase`. Can I complete this without change the folder name?

Comment: I see, the `context.xml` in two different location is not conform to the same rule.